# I can't click on HTML button

Tags: javascript, css, html, facebook

You guys always help with my questions and I'm forever grateful for that!
I'm still new to programming and I'm having an issue with an HTML button. It's supposed to be a "message us" button that will connect to FB and then people can send a message to the fan page. The button works on just one page but we want to place this is some other pages where we're getting traffic but when I add it, it doesn't let me click on it, like it's just an image. I attached the code below.

You guys rock! Thank you in advance for your great suggestions!

```html
<style>
.msgbtn{padding:0 16px;border-radius:6px;background:#4fa7f9;color:white;font-weight:bold;width:120px;}
.msgbtn img{height:32px;width:36px;padding:4px 0;float:left;}
.msgbutoon a{color: white; text-decoration:none;}
.msgbutoon{padding:6px 10px;}
</style>
<div class="msgbutoon">
    <a href="https://m.me/903262919698329" target="popup"
        onclick="window.open('https://m.me/903262919698329','popup','width=600,height=500'); return false;">
        <div class="msgbtn">
            <img src="https://www.feelsocial.io/images/fbmsgr.png">
            <span style="height:40px; line-height:40px;">Message Us</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it ad block? In the console I see. `Blocked opening 'https://m.me/903262919698329' in a new window because the request was made in a sandboxed frame whose 'allow-popups' permission is not set.`

Comment: That code is working to me: https://jsfiddle.net/e9teksub/

Comment: @AndFisher I have no idea, I copied that code and pasted it on my home page and it's working but when I copy it to a landing page or sales page then it doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thank you for your help!

Comment: In the console, do you have any JS errors on your other pages that might be halting execution?

Comment: _“I copied that code and pasted it on my home page and it's working but when I copy it to a landing page or sales page then it doesn't work. Any suggestions?”_ – show us the actual page where it is not working.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this href to your anchor tag `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Comment: `_blank` would cause a whole new window. `popup` refers to the named window created by the onClick event. There may be a timing issue but `_blank` is certainly not what he wants.

Comment: @Cfreak Hello! Thank you for your comments, really appreciate it. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: @stackoverfloweth thank you for trying to help me, really appreciate it!